# Identify 2000 New Holland Connector

Tags: connector

This electrical connector is from a 2000 New Holland Tractor.  The tractor uses a 12V system and this 2 wire connector goes from the wiring harness to the fuel sender.  This connector appears to be weatherproof.  Edge on the connector appears to be circular with two slots on the female end and a tab and ramp on the male end.

[image]
The picture is the female part of the connector.  On the male part of the connector on the ramp it says (I think) "EPC" with a small "32" near it.

If you can identify this connector I'd appreciate it.

I'd like to purchase an identical connector (male and female) because I'd like to splice in a new wire AND use the existing connector shown.  So I'd like to know a manufacturer and a model #.  If you have a link to the exact part that would be amazing.  Here is another picture.

[image] (female part edge on)

[image] (male part with ramp text)

Per the original comment this goes from the fuel sender in the fuel tank to the main wiring harness and appears to be weatherproof.

[image]

(male connector edge on, note what appears to be red O ring and ramp and tab edge on at 90 of each other.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you say "identify" what exact information are you looking for? You've already stated it goes to the "fuel sender". Can you better explain your need here?

Comment: Can you take a photo of the connector connection point and let us know what it connects to?

Comment: Please associate this post with your account by by using the forms located [in this post](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). I've edited in the stuff you put in as answers.

Comment: Is "2000" the year or the model? If it is the year, what is the model of the tractor?

Comment: 2000 is the year.  The tractor is New Holland Boomer TC35D (TC35D is the model)